# How to call a stored procedure from MSSQL into grails

Tags: sql-server, grails, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure thats works, which selects depending on the where clause. However when i try to call it from my grails application i get error saying index 1 out of range. My code is as follows

```
class SQLTestController {

    def dataSource

    def index() {

        Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
       def result =  sql.call("SelectFromTemp","Test")

               [result:result]

    }
```

I want to pass the returned values as the result then display it in my view. "SelectFromTemp" is my procedure name and I am passing the param "Test" My sp is

```
    SelectFromTemp(
@headertestcase varchar(max)
)
AS
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
Select * from dbo.tempTable where HeaderTestCase=@headertestcase
```

(Tried the suggestion that mentioned to use http://groovy.codehaus.org/Database+features)

```
sql.call '{call SelectFromTemp(?)}', ['Test', Sql.VARCHAR], { dwells ->
println dwells //
```

}

Comment: Shouldn't this read `... '{call SelectFromTemp(?, ?)}' ...` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can look in the [Groovy Documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Database+features) about "Stored Procedure Support". Example:

```
sql.call '{call Hemisphere(?, ?, ?)}', ['Guillaume', 'Laforge', Sql.VARCHAR], { dwells ->
    println dwells // => Northern Hemisphere
}
```

Comment: not working still tried the way u mentioned. result shows null.I says  The index 2 is out of range

Comment: Ok, so the error "The index 2 is out of range" it's because your procedure have just one parameter. I don't know if you can return a result from a query like that, maybe you will need to populate a temporary table and query this table in Grails.